# Wrap table tag with div tag using php

Tags: php, wordpress, dom, domdocument, createelement

I am using WordPress.
I would like to enclose `<table>` tag with `<div>` tag using php of wordpress. As below.

### as is

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>txt<br>txt</th><th>txt</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>txt</td><td>txt</td></tr>
        <tr><td>txt</td><td>txt</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### to be

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>txt<br>txt</th><th>txt</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>txt</td><td>txt</td></tr>
            <tr><td>txt</td><td>txt</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried the following code and it did not work well.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_table_outer');

function insert_table_outer($html) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
    for ($i=0;$i<$tables->length;$i++) {
        $parent = $doc->createElement('div');
        $table = $tables->item($i);
        $parent->appendChild($table);
    }
    $out = mb_convert_encoding($doc->saveHTML(), 'utf-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new div element and appending the table to it - but then you don’t do anything with this new div, you just let it go to waste ... You need to insert it into the document, at the position of the original table element.